# php - how can i sort my id in ascending order

Tags: php

This is my code, i need to sort the `$id` in ascending order.

```
<?php
    require("db.php");  
    $SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM enquiryforms";          
    $Result = mysql_query($SQLstring, $DBConnection);


        while ( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) == true) {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $name = $row["name"];
            $messages = $row["messages"];   
            $services = $row["services"];
            $email = $row["email"];
            $datetime = $row["datetime"];
            echo "<b>ID : $id</b> <br>Email : $email ";
            echo "<p class='contentfont1'><b>Enquiry by $name on $datetime</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Messages :</b> <br> $messages <br>";
            echo "<b>Services required :</b> $services";               
            echo "</p><hr>";
        }


    mysql_close($DBConnection); 


?>
```

In my website the `$id` is jumble up.

Example.

Lets say i have 10 ID.

Instead of going by `ID : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Its jumble up by `ID : 1 3 7 9 2 4 5 8 10`

Would like to know where i can insert the `sort()` function.

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM enquiryforms ORDER BY id ASC` in the query?

Comment: +1. Usually you should place as much logic as possible in your query since it's faster and easier than processing data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by on SQL. So something like "SELECT * FROM enquiryforms ORDER BY id";